# Microsoft VBA Editor: assign other keyboard shortcuts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, vba

The Microsoft VBA Editor (for Excel, Word, etc.) has a number of keyboard shortcuts for certain frequent actions, e.g. "F8" for "Step into a procedure for step by step debugging".

I want to assign to those actions, and especially the F8 one, some other shortcut, because exactly F8 is used on my system for something different I necessarily have to run in parallel to programming VBA.

Is there a way to alter the preset shortcuts of the VBA editor?

Comment: Not really - https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/866